# Autofill the cells with VBA Code with conditions from various columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have around 8 columns Order Type, Phase, Units, Product code, Business Type, Customer name, Demand type and Product type. Each and every column has its own variety of Data. And based on this data I have to create a specific column which will be contain the values as 1-4-2-4-2-3-6-12.

Meaning first column will give 1.
2nd column will give a 4 digit number based on the type of data.
3rd column will give a 2 digit number based on the type of data.
.
.
.
8th column will give a 12 digit number based on the type of data

Is there a way to automate this process? Or do I have to do it all manually?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have read through your question a couple of times and I am still not clear what it is exactly that you hope to accomplish. Can you be more specific? Please include some examples of your data, your desired output, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: One thing you might try is to record a macro and then edit it to see how it works. This might be helpful to you. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b

Comment: Do you just want to =CONCATENATE() the numbers?

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. But the problem with macro is that I have more than 1 choices in al these 8 columns. So I think VBA is my only option. Correct me if I am wrong. Thankyou once again.

Comment: Concatenate is definitely a part of the answer, but setting up the conditions is the biggest challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is on Sheet 1 in columns A to H, this code generates the unique id for each type of data and fills in column I with the formatted value. The numbers allocated to each type are shown on Sheet 2.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub macro()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim dict(7) As Object, lastuid(7) As Long
    Dim digits, i As Long, r As Long, iLastRow As Long
    Dim c As Integer, s As String, key

    digits = Array("0", "0000", "00", "0000", "00", "000", _
                   "000000", "000000000000")
    
    For i = 1 To 7
        Set dict(i) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Next
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' header row 1
    For r = 2 To iLastRow
        s = "1"
        For c = 1 To 7
            key = Trim(ws.Cells(r, c + 1))
            If Not dict(c).exists(key) Then
                lastuid(c) = lastuid(c) + 1
                dict(c).Add key, Format(lastuid(c), digits(c))
            End If
            s = s & "-" & dict(c).Item(key)
        Next
        Cells(r, 9) = s
    Next

   ' output code allocations to sheet 2
    ws.Columns("I").AutoFit
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(2)
    For c = 1 To 7
        r = 1
        For Each key In dict(c).keys
           ws.Cells(r, c) = key & "=" & dict(c)(key)
           r = r + 1
        Next
    Next
    ws.Columns("A:G").AutoFit
 
    MsgBox iLastRow & " rows scanned on " & wb.Sheets(1).Name, vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope this works and I will tell you if that has worked or not. Thanks once again!